# how to get all elements by id PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, getelementbyid

I've tried to print using looping but it is not printing the next element.
Please give me a simple example which explains best. using PHP DOM
Secondly can I get some Xth element which has that `id`.

**update**

Thanks. I got error when creating elements with same `id` so changed it to `class` (sorry am newbie to programming, thanks for uplifting me). So can you please let me know how I can extract all the elements those which are having same class name and Secondly can I get some Xth element from the document which has that class name.

Comment: You can't have more than one element in a document with a given ID.

Comment: I wanna return all div elements with the `id`

Comment: The ID value must be unique within the document. No DOM library will give you more than one element from getElementById() - the clue's in the name :-)

Comment: ID is meant to be unique. Multiple elements having the same ID is a bad practice.

Comment: any method for extracting all class elements like `getElementById()`

Comment: @pbvamsi `document.getElementsByClassName()`, I don’t know if it is implemented in php-dom though. However you can always write your own implementation to abstract the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer  this link

u may use this 
 http://uk.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php

```
$node = $parentnode->firstChild;
 do {
// do something
} while ($node = $node->nextSibling);
```

or this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeList->length; ++$i) {
    $nodeName = $nodeList->item($i)->nodeName;
    $nodeValue = $nodeList->item($i)->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have two or more elements with the same `id` in HTML, you will receive error like this:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: ID myid
>   already defined in Entity

Because you cannot have more than one element with the same `id`. If you have only one:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('
    <html>
        <body>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div id="myid">myid1</div>
        </body>
    </html>
');

$element = $dom->getElementById('myid');
echo $element->nodeValue."<br>";
```

Also, you can use [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) or [`XPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Answer (score 2):

use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$html = file_get_html('index.php');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('div') as $element)
   echo $element->id. '<br>';
```

or specific div

```
// Find all <div> which attribute id=foo
$ret = $html->find('div[id=foo]');
```

Comment: thanks. But neither of it is returning any thing